# Automatic syntax checking in Vivado doesn't work for testbenches?

Tags: vhdl, vivado, syntax-checking, test-bench

When I edit a VHDL testbench (simulation source) in Vivado (project mode), background syntax checking seems to be disabled: Obvious syntax errors like missing semicolons or undefined signals are not underlined with a squiggly red line (as in all design sources).

Is there a way to activate automatic background syntax checking for test benches? Could there be another reason why some files are not syntax-checked?

Comment: This question might be more suited to the Xilinx forums to be honest. It's not really a coding issue.

Comment: You got a point there ... I'll post the question at the Xilinx forum as well and cross-reference answers.

If there are no objections here, I'd like to leave the question in SO as well: Lots of my students (and other beginners certainly as well) are unnerved by this issue and they will most likely check SO first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be missing feature: 
[Xilinx Forums: No-syntax-highlighting-for-VHDL-testbenches](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Design-Entry/No-syntax-highlighting-for-VHDL-testbenches/td-p/765967)